# How do 2d arrays work in C when using typedef?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, declaration, typedef

Lecture Slide question that I need help on:
[image: Lecture Slide question that I need help on:]

I missed my lecture today, so I have no idea what is going on for this question in the lecture slides. My instinct tells me it would be C. and N x M matrix (row x col), but I'm not too sure.
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`double X_t[N]` denotes the type of an array with `N` elements of the type double.

`X_t A[M];` is a declaration of an array with `M` elements that have the type `double[N]`.

So this declaration is equivalent to

```
double A[M][N];
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    enum { M = 2, N = 5 };
    typedef double X_t[N];
    
    printf( "sizeof( X_t ) = %zu\n", sizeof( X_t ) );
    
    putchar( '\n' );
    
    X_t A[M];
    
    printf( "sizeof( A ) = %zu\n", sizeof( A ) );
    printf( "sizeof( A[0] ) = %zu\n", sizeof( A[0] ) );
    printf( "sizeof( A ) / sizeof( A[0] ) = %zu\n", sizeof( A ) / sizeof( A[0] ) );
    

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
sizeof( X_t ) = 40

sizeof( A ) = 80
sizeof( A[0] ) = 40
sizeof( A ) / sizeof( A[0] ) = 2
```

So it is seen that the array `A` has two elements with the size `40` bytes that is equivalent to `N * sizeof( double )`.

Answer (score 4):

It's b, and MxN array of doubles.

```
typedef double X_t[N];
```

defines `X_t` as an array of `N` doubles.

When you make an array of these, each `X_t` is a row. So

```
X_t A[M];
```

creates `M` rows of this.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the way to think it through:

```
X_t A[M];
```

`A` is an M-element array of *something* - that *something* is `X_t`.  So right away that eliminates c as a possible answer.

Now you look at the definition of `X_t`.  For the moment, pretend that `typedef` isn't there:

```
double X_t[N];
```

This declares `X_t` as an N-element array of `double`.  When we add the `typedef` keyword:

```
typedef double X_t[N];
```

this means `X_t` is an *alias* for the type "N-element array of `double`".  So, if `A` is an M-element array of `X_t`, and `X_t` is an alias for "N-element array of `double`", then the type of `A` is "M-element array of N-element array of `double`", or "MxN array of `double`."  It's equivalent to writing

```
double A[M][N];
```

Since the `[]` operator is postfix, anytime you substitute an array `typedef` with its "naked" equivalent you put the substituted array size on the *right*.  Assume the following typedefs:

```
typedef double A_type[M];  // A_type is an array of double
typedef A_type B_type[N];  // B_type is an array of A_type
typedef B_type C_type[O];  // C_type is an array of B_type
```

and this declaration

```
C_type x;
```

We want to know what the actual type of `x` is, so we do the following:

1. `x` is an object of type `C_type`.  `C_type` is a typedef name for the type "O-element array of `B_type`", so we replace `C_type` with `B_type [O]`.  Since the `[]` operator is postfix, the `[O]` goes to the rightmost side of the declarator:

   ```
   B_type x[O];
   ```

   `x` is an O-element array of type `B_type`.  `B_type` is a typedef name for the type "N-element array of `A_type`".  As in the previous step, we replace `B_type` with `A_type [N]` and put the `[N]` on the rightmost side of the declarator:

   ```
   A_type x[O][N];
   ```

   `x` is an O-element array of N-element arrays of `A_type`.  `A_type` is a typedef name for the type "M-element array of `double`".  We replace `A_type` with `double [M]`, and again the `[M]` goes to the rightmost side of the declarator, leaving us with:

   ```
   double x[O][N][M];
   ```